# Catkin Make Error Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just the copy'n'paste of the console...

```
aswin@aswinpc:~/nash_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/aswin/nash_ws
Source space: /home/aswin/nash_ws/src
Build space: /home/aswin/nash_ws/build
Devel space: /home/aswin/nash_ws/devel
Install space: /home/aswin/nash_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/aswin/nash_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/aswin/nash_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetRecoveryInfo
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetSearchPosition
Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetDistanceToObstacle
Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetNormal
[  0%] Built target _hector_nav_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GetRobotTrajectory
[  0%] Built target _velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelodyneScan
[  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_baroSample
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_sensorSample
Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BaroSensorSample
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GnssSensorSample
Built target _velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelodynePacket
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Internal
Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_gnssSample
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_orientationEstimate
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_velocityEstimate
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_XsensQuaternion
[  0%] Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ImuSensorSample
[  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target _custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_positionEstimate
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target map_to_image_node
[  0%] Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Faultlog
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Dynamics
Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ConfigCmd
Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/segway.cfg: /home/aswin/nash_ws/devel/include/segway_ros/segwayConfig.h /home/aswin/nash_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/segway_ros/cfg/segwayConfig.py
Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Status
[  0%] Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AuxPower
Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Configuration
/home/aswin/nash_ws/build/segway_v3/segway_ros/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh: 4: exec: /home/aswin/nash_ws/src/segway_v3/segway_ros/cfg/segway.cfg: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [/home/aswin/nash_ws/devel/include/segway_ros/segwayConfig.h] Error 126
make[1]: *** [segway_v3/segway_ros/CMakeFiles/segway_ros_gencfg.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  1%] [  1%] [  1%] [  1%] [  1%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target imu_attitude_to_tf_node
Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Propulsion
Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target pose_and_orientation_to_imu_node
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248138/catkin-make-error-invoking-%22make--j8--l8%22-failed/) by [Aswin Sarang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27924/aswin-sarang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) on 2016-11-15**:
try "sudo catkin_make".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-15**:
@Aswin Sarang: please add a bit more descriptive text to your question. As it is, this is just a dump of an error message. Without some context we're only going to be able to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have a permissions issue:

```
Built target _segway_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Configuration
/home/aswin/nash_ws/build/segway_v3/segway_ros/setup_custom_pythonpath.sh: 4: exec: /home/aswin/nash_ws/src/segway_v3/segway_ros/cfg/segway.cfg: **Permission denied**
```

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1